# Android-Azure-Android Communication

Tags: android, azure

I am new to Azure and Android. I am planning to do a project which involves communication of sensor data between Android based Mobile Phones through Azure as an intermediate.

The phones will be having internet connection either through WiFi or GPRS.

Real Time sensor data should be updated to Azure site, and the same real time data should be accessed by the second Android phone.

How should i implement this and what storage is fast enought for the real time update in Azure?

Regards,
Anil

Answer (score 0):

"Real time" is one of those phrases that means different things to different people. For some "real time" means responses in nanoseconds, to others it means responses in a few seconds. It's also relevant to know what kind of data volumes you need.

The fastest approach is probably to use something like a REST service that stores data in a shared cache of some kind (`memcached` or similar) and asynchronously store the data in a durable store such as Azure's own table storage. `memcached` typically has a response time of a few milliseconds.

Bear in mind that if you're using *any* cloud-based system you will need to factor in the latency to the cloud servers themselves. This will typically outweigh the latency of your processing: from here, for instance, I typically see a raw ping time of ~150 milliseconds to the local Azure data centre.

So if you're after *true* real time and your phones are close to each other, consider a peer-to-peer architecture instead where the phones talk to each other.

Answer (score 0):

I work on behalf of Microsoft UK and before I go any further I hope I'm not breaking an forum rules by posting here. I didn't spot anything in the T&C's so hopefully this'll be OK!

It looks like you might be interested in a free six week training course direct from Microsoft.

The course is called Six Weeks of Azure and will be starting on the 23rd January 2012. The project includes surgeries, drop- in labs, special offers and weekly webinars to get you up to speed and lets you pick and choose the course modules to suit your needs.

This link explains more: http://sixweeksofazure.wordpress.com/sign-up-for-six-weeks-of-azure/

It's 100%, and run by Microsoft and I hope it's of interest to you.

Thanks,

Richard